# what is curl doing differently to httr::POST that causes 400 bad request?

Tags: r, curl, httr

I'm trying to query data from the [Materials Project web API](https://github.com/materialsproject/mapidoc) in R.

The documentation provides an example query which is conducted using both `curl` and `python`. I've copied the `curl` command below.

```
curl -s --header "X-API-KEY: <YOUR-API-KEY>" \
    https://materialsproject.org/rest/v2/query \
    -F criteria='{"elements": {"$in": ["Li", "Na", "K"], "$all": ["O"]}, "nelements": 2}' \
    -F properties='["formula", "formation_energy_per_atom"]'
```

From reading the [httr quickstart guide](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/quickstart.html), it seems to me I should be able to reproduce this query with:

```
library(httr)
POST(url = "https://www.materialsproject.org/rest/v2/query",
     config = add_headers("X-API-KEY" = "<YOUR-API-KEY>",     
     body = list(criteria = "{'elements': {'$in': ['Li', 'Na', 'K'], '$all': ['O']}, 'nelements': 2}",
                 properties = "['formula', 'formation_energy_per_atom']"),
     encode = "multipart",
     verbose())
```

But while the `curl` command returns JSON data from the Materials Project database, my `R` query returns a `HTTP/1.1 400 BAD REQUEST`. What is curl doing differently than `httr` in the codes above?

I've tried putting `-v` on curl and comparing it to the (`verbose()`) output above, but curl don't show what it's putting in the multipart form.

```
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------d2ef2f3982185118
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Tue, 27 Dec 2016 21:18:58 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
< Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
< Connection: close
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: application/json
```

Meanwhile `httr` shows:

```
-> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------5b4873dbc9cd
-> 
<- HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
>> ------------------------------5b4873dbc9cd
>> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="criteria"
>> 
>> {'elements': {'$in': ['Li', 'Na', 'K'], '$all': ['O']}, 'nelements': 2}
>> ------------------------------5b4873dbc9cd
>> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="properties"
>> 
>> ['formula', 'formation_energy_per_atom']
>> ------------------------------5b4873dbc9cd--
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's truly a terrible, poorly thought out & lazily implemented API. They seem to like Python so it's unsurprising this would be the case.

The following works:

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

list(
  criteria=toJSON(list(
    elements=list(
      `$in`=c("Li", "Na", "K"),
      `$all`=c("0")
    ),
    nelements=unbox(2)
  )),
  properties=toJSON(c("formula", "formation_energy_per_atom"))
) -> params

POST(url="https://www.materialsproject.org/rest/v2/query",
     add_headers(`X-API-KEY`=Sys.getenv("MATERIALS_PROJECT_API_KEY")),
     body=params,
     encode="multipart", verbose()) -> res
```

and here's the `verbose()` output to prove it:

```
-> POST /rest/v2/query HTTP/1.1
-> Host: www.materialsproject.org
-> User-Agent: libcurl/7.51.0 r-curl/2.3 httr/1.2.1
-> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
-> Accept: application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*
-> X-API-KEY: wouldntyouliketoknow
-> Content-Length: 344
-> Expect: 100-continue
-> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------34f08173ce0a7818
-> 
<- HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
>> --------------------------34f08173ce0a7818
>> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="criteria"
>> 
>> {"elements":{"$in":["Li","Na","K"],"$all":["0"]},"nelements":2}
>> --------------------------34f08173ce0a7818
>> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="properties"
>> 
>> ["formula","formation_energy_per_atom"]
>> --------------------------34f08173ce0a7818--

<- HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<- Date: Wed, 28 Dec 2016 02:08:08 GMT
<- Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
<- Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
<- Content-Encoding: gzip
<- Content-Length: 258
<- Connection: close
<- Content-Type: application/json
<-
```

It's *super* picky about the query string structure. They really should have just accepted a JSON body and have been done with it. But half-REDACTED is the way of python folk.

Oh gosh, I just noticed it's a CentOS server supplying the replies. Yep. Those folks really do like pain.